# Xamarin ObjC binding callback not called

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a Xamarin-Objective C binding project (see here: https://github.com/bbhsu2/XamarinAdMarvelBinding). Fundamentally, it works and I can load clickable ads.

So I implement the AdMarvelDelegate interface on my ViewController class, but important implemented methods are not getting called:

```
public class CategoryViewController : UITableViewController, IAdMarvelDelegate
{
    /*Initializing stuff*/

    public void GetAdSucceeded() //not called
    {
        Console.WriteLine("succeeded!");
    }

    public void GetAdFailed() //not called
    {
        Console.WriteLine("failed!"); 
        AppDelegate.Shared.AddAdBanner();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on why GetAdSucceeded and GetAdFailed are not called?  In the binding project I have:

```
    [Export("getAdSucceeded")]
    void GetAdSucceeded();

    [Export("getAdFailed")]
    void GetAdFailed();
```

which I believe are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the corresponding members in AdMarvelDelegate are optional (i.e. they don't have the `[Abstract]` attribute in the binding), you'll need the [Export] attribute on those methods:

```
public class CategoryViewController : UITableViewController, IAdMarvelDelegate
{
    [Export ("getAdSucceeded")]
    public void GetAdSucceeded()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("succeeded!");
    }

    [Export("getAdFailed")]
    public void GetAdFailed()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("failed!"); 
        AppDelegate.Shared.AddAdBanner();
    }
}
```